# Minimal amount of laws to deduce the rest of First Order Logic?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

Consider the FOL of standard set theory.

In any FOL expression in its most formal form, we have four types of objects

$$\color{blue}{\forall} \color{green}{x}(\color{blue}{\exists} \color{green}{y} (\color{green}{x}\in \color{green}{y})\color{red}{\wedge}(\color{green}{y}\color{purple}{\notin}\color{green}{x}))$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Quantifiers}}:$ $\forall$ and $\exists$

$\color{green}{\text{Variables}}:$ $a,b,c,\dots,w,w_0,w_1,\dots$

$\color{red}{\text{Operations}}:$ $\neg,\implies,\iff,\wedge$ and $\vee$

$\color{purple}{\text{Atoms}}:$ $w_0\in w_1$ or $w_0\notin w_1$

**Operation Minimization:**

If we were trying to minimize this system, we can opt out from having any operations besides the negation $\neg$ and some operation acting as a universal operator, such as $\implies$. I.e, we can define all other binary operations in terms of $\neg$ and $\implies$.

For example, we can simply define $p\vee q\equiv p\implies\neg q$, as these have classically equivalent truth tables.

**Atom Minimization:**

Furthermore, since $\in$ and $\notin$ are the only atomic relationships between variables in set theory (discounting $\subseteq$, as that can be defined in terms of $\in$), we can define $w_0 \notin w_1$ as $\neg(w_0\in w_1)$.

**Variable Minimization:**

The amount of variable symbols is countably infinite, and thus cannot be minimized (not that they need to be).

**Quantifier minimization:**

Since $\forall w_0(\phi(x))\iff \neg(\exists w_0(\neg(\phi(x))))$ for any formula $\phi$, we can define one of the quantifiers in terms of the other. Without loss of generality, let's keep $\forall$ and define
$$\exists w_0(\phi(x))\equiv \neg(\forall w_0(\neg(\phi(x)))).$$

---

Finally, we are left with a logic only in terms of a countable set of variables, one quantifier $\forall$, one unary operation $\neg$, one binary operation $\implies$, and one atomic variable relationship $\in$. But we are not quite done minimizing!

---

**Law minimization:**

Syntax alone doesn't suffice for a formal system! We need to define the laws/axioms/transformation rules.

[This list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms) shows that the underlying zero'th order logic has dozens of laws alone. However, many can be deduced from prior ones.

For example, [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), [Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation_elimination), and [De Morgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) suffice to deduce [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Of course, we also must define the first order laws too, such as

$$\forall w_0(\phi(w_0)),\forall w_0(\psi(w_0))\vdash \forall w_0(\phi(w_0)\wedge\psi(w_0))$$

So my question is,

> What is the minimal amount of FOL laws required to deduce the rest of the classical laws?

Any insight would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Seems you're interested in logical operators' [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness). It may be helpful to check out this recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312153/functional-completeness-proving-nleftrightarrow-is-functionally-complete/4312708#4312708) of mine...

Comment: See e.g. [List of Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) as well as [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Delightful. I think that is precisely what I am looking for, if not, incredibly related at the least.